# Importing function without class gives me error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have simple functions addition and sub in 1 file called simple_math.py. I imported simple_math in different file. When I try to call simple_math.addition(1,2). I get an error

AttributeError: module 'simple_math' has no attribute 'addition'

This is how my codes looks

```
#simple_math.py

    def addition (x,y):
        """adds"""
        return x+y
    
    
    def sub(x,y):
        """subtracts"""
        return x-y

# testing_result.py

import simple_math
simple_math.addition(2,3)
```

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. It works for me and I get the return value `5`. Admittedly I did have to adjust the indentation of `simple_math.py`

Comment: try from simple_math import addition. Are the files in the same folder?

Comment: @ RMR AttributeError: module 'simple_math' has no attribute 'addition' when I try to import using from simple_math import addition

Comment: can you show the tree structure of files vs folders

Comment: You need to check all the `simple_math.py` files you have on your computer. It could be that your program above references one without the `addition` function.

Comment: @Epsi95, both files are in same folder.

Comment: @quamrana, that's what I thought too so I tested with different weird names. No luck

Comment: Well, I'm sorry there is nothing we can do. What you have done is how it is supposed to work, as others here have demonstrated.

Comment: and what you did with choosing alternate names for your `.py` file was next on my list to try.

Comment: can you print `print(dir(simple_math))`  in your testing_result.py @Sam?

Comment: Another thought has occurred to me. Try adding `print('in simple_math.py')` somewhere in the file. This should execute if you just have `import simple_math`.

Comment: What is the output of `import simple_math; print(simple_math.__file__)`?